# Stripe Webhooks on a multisite?

Tags: webform-civicrm, hooks, stripe

I've just updated a multi-site with the latest Stripe extension and I get the message to update the webhooks. Did this on another site earlier I was able to just follow the links and it updated as it should.

However on this site, when I try to click on https://mysite.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fstripe%2Ffix-webhook it redirects to either the homepage or the admin page (depending on whether I followed the link via the system status page of the admin menu).

Is there a way I can set this manually?

Related to this, I have a membership webform taking payments and it's not recording the payment or membership when I test it - I'm assuming it's because it's the webhooks are not updated?

Comment: Anything in the logs or backtrace? This might be one to post in the Stripe extension's issue queue: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/issues